# Problem with sort in scala, got "Diverging implicit expansion ....." error. Sorting a list of tuples based on its first element but in reverse order

Tags: list, scala, collections, functional-programming, scala-collections

I am trying to sort a list of tuples in Scala, the following code will result in error:

```
List("a"->1,"b"->2, "c"->3).sortBy(-_._1)

error: diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[B]
starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering
       List("a"->1,"b"->2, "c"->3).sortBy(-_._1)
                                         ^
```

but the code below works just fine:

```
List("a"->1,"b"->2, "c"->3).sortBy(_._1)

res39: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3))
```

The only difference is the negative sign in `sortBy`!

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no such thing as a negative `String`, you can't sort by it. You can reverse-sort element types that can't be negated, either by reversing the sorted results...

```
List("a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3).sortBy(_._1).reverse
```

...or by replacing the implicit `Ordering` with an explicit reversed `Ordering`.

```
List("a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3).sortBy(_._1)(Ordering[String].reverse)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs, because `-` method is not defined on `String`. The following works just fine:

```
List("a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3).sortBy(-_._2)
```

It's because `-` is defined for `Int`.

Maybe you meant something like:

```
List("a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3).sortBy(-_._1.length)
```